# Using the MS sync fx, some changes fail to apply

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using the sync framework to sync between an SQL-Server and an SDF. I'm using VS-2010 Local Database Cache to do the actual sync, with the ConflictResolver set to client wins.

I tried to sync changes between the two, having modified only one side, and yet some records fail to sync to the other side (from SDF to SQL). 
In the SyncStatistics returned from the Agent.Synchronize() method, I saw that the *SyncStatistics.DownloadChangesFailed* value was set to 9.

I could not however glean any more information.

Can anybody help me understand this? I don't think there should be a conflict here, but if there is - shouldn't the Client-Wins setting be sufficient?

Thanks in Advance,
Assaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I forgot to add **server side** handling of conflicts.

Adding that, I got everything to work.
Assaf